# Set Map location after successful $http callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

### Problem

In my AngularJS controller I request some location data from a RESTful API (Google Maps API in this example) with the `$http` service. After a successful request I want to update my Google Map and set the center location for the map. In my example the map location parameters don't receive any update from my controller.

### What I tried

I tried to move `$scope.options` inside and outside of the success callback, but both don't work for me. The map doesn't receive the location data. I guess I use the wrong `$scope` inside the success callback handler. I don't have any clue how to solve this and couldn't find any similar questions on here.

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('simple-map', ['AngularGM'])

.controller('SimpleMapCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.location = {};

    $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=San%20Francisco%20Bicycle%20Route%2060,%20San%20Francisco,%20Kalifornien,%20USA&sensor=false')
    .success(function(res) {
        $scope.location = res.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log($scope.location.lat); // 37.7502819
        console.log($scope.location.lng); // -122.3874909

        $scope.options = {
          map: {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                        $scope.location.lat,
                        $scope.location.lng
             ),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
          }
        };

    });  

});
```

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/PwkLU/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `gmMap` directive your using isn't watching for changes on the `gm-map-options` attribute where you're loading your center and zoom- that's just used for initialization (and your data isn't ready at initialization since you don't set it until the `get` succeeds).

However, the directive does watch center and zoom according [to the docs](http://dylanfprice.github.io/angular-gm/1.0.0/docs/#/api/angulargm.directive%3agmMap):

> The gm-center, gm-zoom, gm-bounds, and
>   gm-map-type-id variables ... have
>   bi-directional association, i.e. drag or zoom the map and they will 
>   update, update them and the map will change.

So it works if, rather than using `gm-map-options` you assign your center and zoom `options` properties to `gm-center` and `gm-zoom` like so:

```
<gm-map gm-map-id="'simpleMap'" gm-center="options.map.center" gm-zoom="options.map.zoom" class="map" gm-map-options="options.map">
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PwkLU/4/)

Comment: Thank you, I should have spent more time on reading the docs. Do you have any recommendations how I could improve the my controller? What would be best practice for fetching data by $http and refreshing elements (i.e. a map) with new data?